# How do I use the pg_restore --list to inspect the contents of a non-restored directory?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-restore

I am trying to inspect the contents of an archive that I just unzipped using the following code

```
pg_restore --list filename
```

I've aslo tried

```
pg_restore --list D:/above_file/filename
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 12

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue.  The answer is that you need to direct the list-file output to a file by specifying the file option as follows:

```
pg_restore --list --file=".\list-file.txt" backupfilepath
```

By default the archive list is sent to StdOut as it is designed to be passed into another pg_restore use-list option. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html) on the file option copied here for ease of reference:

> Specify output file for generated script, or for the listing when used with -l. Use - for stdout.